# Events plugin for irregular / complex events

Tags: events

I have been using the Events Manager plugin, and I like it for the most part. However, I have a client who runs events in a very specific way. Events are (nearly) always on Friday, Saturday and Sunday, and the times are as follows:

- Friday: 6 — 9 pm
- Saturday: 3 — 9 pm
- Sunday: 3 — 9 pm

In addition, they'll often have an opening night on a Tuesday or Thursday. So I would like to have recurring events, with different times for different days, and with exceptions (adding a day, or even removing one if they happen to be closed for a day).

There's a plugin called Events Organiser that allows inclusion of other days, but it appears to be pretty buggy. I would rather stay with Events Manager, if possible, but would move to something else if it definitely worked. Maybe the trick is to extend Events Manager with ACF? Anyway, if anyone knows a way to accomplish this, please let me know.